# WPF, XNA, SlimDX ... suggestion for a CAD-like desktop application? (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xna, directx, slimdx

This is what I have to do:

To build a CAD-like application that loads a point cloud (i.e. thousands of 3D points representing a 3D object) from file, allows the users to manipulate the points (i.e. change the shape by moving the points), do a lot of calculations the points on the points (e.g. finding the intersection points between lines and surfaces, detect a point is above or under a surface etc., measure the distances between points, or points to surface etc.), and then save the modified points to file.

It also provides basic CAD-like UI features such as zoom in/out, pan the view, rotation the camera etc.

Speed is the major concern.

Instead of writing my own functions for matrix operation and defining my own point/line/surface classes, I would like to use existing libraries/APIs to do the job.

I know WPF, XNA and SlimDX provides the API to do 3D geometric calculations and all of them are finally calling DirectX, but I'm just newbie to all of them. I'm wondering:

1. Which one (or some other suggestion) could give better performance in speed.
2. My understanding about DirectX's 3D functions is that it mainly deals with gaming graphics / screen outputs, is it also suitable for data-level calculations(i.e. use the 3D functions to manipulate the point data, calculate the distances etc., but not outputting it on the screen)? By suitable, I mean if I create thousands of DirectX vertexes and mainpulate them, would it be much slower than using my own data types and structures?
   Pls correct me if my understanding is wrong.
3. If I use WPF, do I need to use XNA as well? I'm kind of mixing up these two things.
4. The application is supposed to run in research lab's PC which doesn't have powerful gaming display card, so does it mean XNA is not preferred?
5. An suggestion about the technologies should be used for this application?

Thanks!!

========update

To make it clearer, the app will load ~108,000 points in 3D, and every points will form surfaces with other adjacent points, so roughly the the same number of 3D surfaces are involved (I'm not generating them at the same time). I will do a lot of 3D geometric and matrix calculations with the point and surfaces, such as intersection, interpolation, transformation etc. , so the speed of the "calculations" is my major concern. Most of the time I will only draw the final result to the screen and the drawing is mainly lines and points, the speed of "drawing" is not a big concern . so it is not really a graphic-intensive app, but a geometric-calculation-intensive app.

After reading the answer and comments, I think of two options:

1. store & calculate the data with primitive data-types, and convert data to the WPF/XNA/SlimDX data structures when drawing them on screen, or
2. use these API's data structures to store, calculation and drawing all those points.

which one is better?

Comment: Sounds like you're just creating a simple 3D model viewer/editor, nothing CAD-specific.  If you are only loading 1000's of points, I can't imagine performance being a big concern - you could honestly probably do this with GDI and still have good performance, even on a crappy machine (don't, though).

Comment: Thx BlueRaja, just updated question. My major concern is the performance of geometric calculations.

Answer (score 7):

1. Honestly, if performance is your
   primary concern I would go with the
   API that gets you closest to the
   hardware. *Less obfuscation = more
   speed.* In that case, from the
   choices you've provided, **SlimDX**
   is the best option, followed by XNA,
   and lastly, WPF.
2. No, DirectX must use efficient data structures and algorithms. Think about it-- would games that utilize DirectX be able to run at a suitable framerate if all DirectX calculations were inherently slow?
3. No, WPF and XNA are mutually exclusive. WPF is a framework for creating responsive and intuitive *user interfaces*. XNA, on the other hand, is a framework for creating games.
4. Not necessarily. What it actually means is that WPF is not preferred, as WPF will offload a lot of work to compatible video cards. If WPF is unable to find a suitable video card, the CPU will take that work instead, resulting in poor performance.
5. As I said before, for a graphics-intensive application such as the one you have described, the closer you can get to the hardware is the better. Native DirectX or SlimDX are good options.

Comment: +1 very succinct, though despite claims by OP, this does *not* seem like a very graphics-intensive application.

Comment: Just as a heads up, SlimDX has the ability to interoperate with WPF, so you can use WPF for the UI bits and SlimDX to do rendering of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered developing your functionality as a plugin for an existing CAD environment?
AutoCAD, for example, has a very powerful c++ sdk (ObjectARX), it also provides a managed .NET API. You can use c# and WPF to develop your extensions. It has existing geometry libraries you can reuse.
Certainly AutoCAD has its price, but there are alternatives. For example BricsCAD. I'm not sure if BricsCAD provides a .NET api though.

Developing an application from scratch would take weeks if not months.
If I were to develop your functionallity as an AutoCAD plugin it would take me a day.

Consider if you really need to roll out own your own 'CAD' environment.

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago, I checked out the limits of XNA. I want to know how much billboards (GPU accelarated) the engine in able to deal with. The result:
Pure XNA: 350k billboards
XNA as rendering context in WPF: 100k billboards

I do not realy know why the engine slow down when rendering to a WinFormHost control. Some debugging shows, that GraphcisDevice.Present()